# No module named 'keras.backend.tensorflow_backend'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, bert-language-model

I am trying to learn from a python script on semantic search that uses sentence transformer-BERT, While compiling this python script (`semantic_search.py`) file I encountered the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "semantic_search.py", line 6, in <module>
    import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend as tb
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

Kindly suggest possible source of error and corrections.

Comment: Did you install the keras package?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with versions of keras and tensorflow. It sounds like this tutorial was written before keras became a part of tensorflow. For more info on why this happened and what version you should use, [see this article](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/10/21/keras-vs-tf-keras-whats-the-difference-in-tensorflow-2-0/).

Probably what you'd need is to change any imports in the script that start with `keras` to `tensorflow.keras`, if you have tensorflow version 2.0 and above. So for that line specifically, you probably want:

```py
import tensorflow.keras.backend as tb
```

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect, the code seems to use keras and not tf.keras, the why is not important. Also note that tf.keras is moving back to being the standalone keras package.

Comment: Can you provide a link to support the statement that keras is moving back to being the standalone keras package? That's news to me, I'd like to be up to date on that if that's correct. Thanks.

Comment: It was mentioned in the README of the keras repo: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/commit/e1a17d32feb5105ffa32c41d4d3ced461a5f5ac9#diff-b335630551682c19a781afebcf4d07bf978fb1f8ac04c6bf87428ed5106870f5

Comment: But in general I do not think that blindly switching from keras to tf.keras is a good solution, as you do not know if there will be additional changes or side effects. Also the code might just not work.

Comment: I tried the command 'import tensorflow.keras.backend as tb' but its giving a different error-Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "semantic_search.py", line 15, in <module>
    tb._SYMBOLIC_SCOPE.value = True
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.backend' has no attribute '_SYMBOLIC_SCOPE'